# Passing PSRemotingJob Object as Parameter in Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell Cmdlet for which I need to pass in a `PSRemotingJob`
object as a parameter.  The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) follows:

```
function My-Cmdlet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,
                   Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [PSRemotingJob[]]$Job
    )

    BEGIN {}

    PROCESS {
        ForEach ($j in $Job) {
            $j
        }
    }

    END {}
}
```

The issue is that when I pass a job into the cmdlet, I get an error, as follows:

```
PS C:\Temp> Invoke-Command -AsJob -CN svr001 -Command {Start-Sleep 10} | My-Cmdlet
My-Cmdlet : Unable to find type [PSRemotingJob]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:63
+ Invoke-Command -AsJob -CN svr001 -Command {Start-Sleep 10} | My-Cmdlet
+                                                              ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (PSRemotingJob:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS C:\Temp>
```

I realize that this should be a simple matter of substituting the correct object
type or fully-qualified object, but I've also tried using
`[System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob]` with the same results.

I'm using Powershell 4.0.

Comment: `System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob` is internal type. You can not express it in PowerShell type syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  Just changing `$Job` to an untyped variable did the trick.  If you'd put that into a regular answer, I'd be glad to give you the up-check and the solution credit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob` is not public type and thus can not be expressed in PowerShell type syntax. But you can use its base public type instead: `[System.Management.Automation.Job]`.